# Capistrano Deploying to Wrong Enviornment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger, capistrano3

I started using Capistrano to deploy my Rails application to different remote servers, however,  deploying to a server using `cap production deploy` sets my RAILS_ENV to deployment instead of production. I have tried forcing the environment by adding `ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'production'` to the environment.rb, but that doesn't seem to fix the problem. I checked the production.log for Passenger, Apache, and Rails and nothing seems to be wrong, except for the incorrect environment deployment. What could be wrong with my Capistrano deployment?

production.rb

```
role :app, %w{deployer@*****}
role :web, %w{deployer@*****}
role :db,  %w{deployer@*****}

# Define server(s)
server '*****', user: 'deployer', roles: %w{web}

# SSH Options
# See the example commented out section in the file
# for more options.
set :ssh_options, {
    forward_agent: false,
    auth_methods: %w(password),
    password: '******',
    user: 'deployer',
}
```

deploy.rb

```
# Define the name of the application
set :application, 'app_pro'

# Define where can Capistrano access the source repository
# set :repo_url, 'https://github.com/[user name]/[application name].git'
set :scm, :git
set :repo_url, 'https://github.com/awernick/app_pros.git'

# Define where to put your application code
set :deploy_to, "/var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/app_dir"
set :pty, true

set :format, :pretty

# Set the post-deployment instructions here.
# Once the deployment is complete, Capistrano
# will begin performing them as described.
# To learn more about creating tasks,
# check out:
# http://capistranorb.com/

# namespace: deploy do

#   desc 'Restart application'
#   task :restart do
#     on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
#       # Your restart mechanism here, for example:
#       execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
#     end
#   end

#   after :publishing, :restart

#   after :restart, :clear_cache do
#     on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
#       # Here we can do anything such as:
#       # within release_path do
#       #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
#       # end
#     end
#   end

# end
```

Capfile

```
# Load DSL and set up stages
require 'capistrano/setup'

# Include default deployment tasks
require 'capistrano/deploy'

# Include tasks from other gems included in your Gemfile
#
# For documentation on these, see for example:
#
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rvm
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv
#   https://github.com/capistrano/chruby
#   https://github.com/capistrano/bundler
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rails
#   https://github.com/capistrano/passenger
#
# require 'capistrano/rvm'
# require 'capistrano/rbenv'
# require 'capistrano/chruby'
  require 'capistrano/bundler'
  require 'capistrano/rails'
  require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
  require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
  require 'capistrano/passenger'

# Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks' if you have any defined
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

*The fields in the files are filled out with the correct information.

Comment: have you tried with `set: :stage....` in deploy/production.rb?

Comment: @rmagnum2002 I did. Capistrano keeps deploying to development regardless. When I set the RailsEnv to development in Passenger, Rails run correctly though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my problem. My problem was occurring because I forgot to add my production secret_key_base as an environment variable in my production server.

Answer (score 1):

In `production.rb` you should have:

```
set :stage, :production
```

or some say this option will not work in v3(I am using v3 and set stage works for me), however you might want to read this in case set stage doesn't work:

http://dylanmarkow.com/blog/2014/01/08/capistrano-3-setting-a-default-stage/

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but normally Capistrano, as long as it does not have any special plugins for Apache or Nginx, deploys the code as it is, your problems appears to come from passenger configuration. It could be it tries to run the server under wrong environment. I don't remember how it is with Apache, but with nginx you have to make sure the line

```
...
passenger_app_env production;
...
```

Is inside /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf

Maybe this could help you with setting up Apache config:
https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerAppEnv

Comment: Passenger sets the environment to production by default. Whenever I try changing my app_env to development, the application runs without a problem. When I set it back to production, the application refuses to execute.